# balanceOf @block

Tags: ethers.js

Hi everyone Im a bit of a noob or at least feel like one....

Im using Ethers.Js and I am trying to get the balance of WETH of a contract at varying block numbers.....

this is where I am currently.....

```
const ethersAbi = [
  // Read-Only Functions
  "function balanceOf(address owner) view returns (uint256)",
  "function HistbalanceOf(address owner, blockNumber) view returns (uint256)",
  "function decimals() view returns (uint8)",
  "function symbol() view returns (string)",
  "function totalSupply() view returns (uint256)",
  // Authenticated Functions
  "function transfer(address to, uint amount) returns (bool)",

  // Events
  "event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint amount)"
];

const WETHerc20Historical = new ethers.Contract(Coins.WETH, ethersAbi, HistoricalRPC);

accumulatedWETHFees = await WETHerc20Historical.balanceOf.call(Contracts.RoyaltyFeeSetter,StaticData.START_BLOCK+(i*BLOCKS_PER_DAY)).then(result => {
        console.log(result)
        return ethers.utils.formatUnits(result._hex,18);
    })
```

when I call this I get the following

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: resolver or addr is not configured for ENS name (argument="name", value="139770120", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.2.0)
    at Logger.makeError (ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1:59669)
    at Logger.throwError (ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1:59874)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1:59983)
    at ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1:306151
    at step (ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1:305047)
    at Object.next (ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1:304307)
    at fulfilled (ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1:303681)
Logger.makeError @ ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1
Logger.throwError @ ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1
Logger.throwArgumentError @ ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1
step @ ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1
fulfilled @ ethers-5.2.umd.min.js:1
load (async)
(anonymous) @ index.js?v=1.33:2564
```

I feel its a stupidly easy question but aftr a good few hours of searching I cant find the answer..... if anyone could help I would appreciate VERY much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that stumbled Accross this:

```
accumulatedWETHFees = await WETHerc20Historical.balanceOf.call(undefined,Contracts.RoyaltyFeeSetter, {
        blockTag:parseInt(StaticData.START_BLOCK)+(i*BLOCKS_PER_DAY)}
      ).then(result => {
        return ethers.utils.formatUnits(result._hex,18);
    })
```

It was to do with the Overrides not being in the correct position.

you mjst Define your Block as **blockTag**